# sub-exponential type upper bound on the Poisson probability

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, large-deviations

I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4065525/upper-bound-for-poisson-distribution) on Math Stack Exchange, though I'm not satisfied with the answer I received.

**Question:**

For a Poisson random variable $Z$ with the parameter $\lambda,\,$ what would be a good upper bound (sub-exponential type perhaps?) for $P(Z \geq \frac{\lambda}{2})$; especially for large $\lambda$?

More generally, is it possible to find a sub-expoential type upper bound for $P(Z \geq \lambda - t)$ for $0\leq t \leq \lambda$?

Any comments (or references) will be appreciated.

Comment: This is the referenced question I think https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4065525/

Comment: @J.J.Green Yes it is

Comment: Why are you not satisfied by the answer received there? And why did you not mention what you'd like to get there?

Comment: I'm looking for a sub-exponential type bound (if possible) rather than something of the form $1-ke^{-c \lambda}\, , k,c>0$.

Comment: But you won't get that, unfortunately. Look at the lower tail $\Pr[X_n \leq \lambda/2]$ for a Binomial$(n,\lambda/n)$, and take the limit as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Do you have taken a look in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05179.pdf ? Further note that if you have good estimation for the tail of the inverse gamma distribution you equally well have good estimations for the Poisson distribution.